# Given the hypercube Q3 of 8 vertices, what is x + 10y where x is the minimum vertex cover set size and y is the maximum independent set size?

Tags: graphs

Sorry for the shoddy formatting in the title, here's something clearer:

Given the hypercube Q<sub>3</sub> of 8 vertices, what is x + 10y where x is the minimum vertex cover set size and y is the maximum independent set size?

I know that a hypercube Q<sub>d</sub> is just a graph with 2<sup>d</sup> vertices consisting of binary strings of length d, and that two vertices are adjacent whenever they differ in exactly one bit, but I'm struggling to put it together conceptually.

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy exercise. Here is a hint.

Notice that Q3 has 12 edges and that all vertices of Q3 have degree 3.
Can you find a lower bound on the size of a vertex cover using the above information?

Once you have such a lower bound, can you find a vertex cover that matches it?

Finally, how is the size of a minimum vertex cover related to the size of a maximum independent set? Recall that, given a set of vertices $S$, $S$ is a vertex cover if **at least one** of the endpoints of each edge belongs to $S$, while $S$ is an independent set if **at most one**  of the endpoints of each edge belongs to $S$.